# Ubuntu 13.04 перенос на новый hdd - проблема

Tags: ubuntu

Проблема заключается в том, что хочу отказаться от старого ноутбучного диска в своем компьютере, но так же хочу сохранить полностью систему со всеми неустановленными и настроенными приложениями. Дело в том, что

1. диски разных конфигураций: старый - размер сектора (логич./физич.): 512B/512B и новый размер сектора (логич./физич.): 512B/4096B
2. этот самый раздел с UEFI boot как раз нормально копируется а, вот второй extended на 2 байта (как я понял не попадает в блок 4096 байт).
3. Собственно проблема не в том как скопировать данные но пока я увидел только одно решение которым сегодня попробую заняться. (Установить ubuntu с нуля а потом через cp -a скопировать все содержимое старого диска. После чего восстановить загрузчик.

Есть следующая структура диска:

```
# parted /dev/sdbGNU Parted 2.3Используется /dev/sdbДобро пожаловать в GNU Parted! Наберите 'help' для просмотра списка команд.(parted) printМодель: ATA Hitachi HTS54161 (scsi)Диск /dev/sdb: 160GBРазмер сектора (логич./физич.): 512B/512BТаблица разделов: msdosНомер  Начало  Конец   Размер  Тип       Файловая система  Флаги 1     1049kB  99,6MB  98,6MB  primary   fat32             загрузочный 2     101MB   160GB   160GB   extended 6     101MB   152GB   152GB   logical   ext4 5     152GB   160GB   8250MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
```

Есть новый HDD

```
# parted /dev/sdaGNU Parted 2.3Используется /dev/sdaДобро пожаловать в GNU Parted! Наберите 'help' для просмотра списка команд.(parted) printМодель: ATA WDC WD10EZEX-00R (scsi)Диск /dev/sda: 1000GBРазмер сектора (логич./физич.): 512B/4096BТаблица разделов: gptНомер  Начало  Конец   Размер  Файловая система  Имя  Флаги
```

Первым делом, что я попробовал это скопировать командой dd диск sdb в диск sda, система запустилась правда сказала, что у меня проблема с UUID диска но запустилась (правда куда-то пропало пару программ не знаю с чем связано может и с привязкой UUID но мне написало что раздел 2 не выровнен ). Далее не помню, что писал т.к. удалил все и методом научного тыка пробую другие варианты. Но как вы можете уже догадатся скорее всего я не компетентен в этом вопросе.

Железо:

```
# lshwbinliz                        описание: Настольный компьютер    продукт: System Product Name (SKU)    производитель: System manufacturer    версия: System Version    серийный №: System Serial Number    разрядность: 64 bits    возможности: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 vsyscall32    кофигурация: boot=normal chassis=desktop family=To be filled by O.E.M. sku=SKU uuid=E025874F-DAD7-DD11-B2ED-10BF48E2AC4B  *-core       описание: Материнская плата       продукт: P8B75-V       производитель: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.       физический ID: 0       версия: Rev X.0x       серийный №: MT7026K01702455       слот: To be filled by O.E.M.     *-firmware          описание: BIOS          производитель: American Megatrends Inc.          физический ID: 0          версия: 0417          date: 05/07/2012          размер: 64KiB          capacity: 8128KiB          возможности: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi     *-cpu          описание: ЦПУ          продукт: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2100 CPU @ 3.10GHz          производитель: Intel Corp.          физический ID: 4          сведения о шине: cpu@0          версия: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2100 CPU @ 3.10GHz          серийный №: To Be Filled By O.E.M.          слот: LGA1155          размер: 1800MHz          capacity: 3800MHz          разрядность: 64 bits          частота: 100MHz          возможности: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave avx lahf_lm arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid cpufreq          кофигурация: cores=2 enabledcores=1 threads=2        *-cache:0             описание: L1 временные данные             физический ID: 5             слот: L1-Cache             размер: 32KiB             capacity: 32KiB             возможности: internal write-back unified        *-cache:1             описание: L2 временные данные             физический ID: 6             слот: L2-Cache             размер: 256KiB             capacity: 256KiB             возможности: internal varies unified        *-cache:2 ВЫКЛЮЧЕНО             описание: L3 временные данные             физический ID: 7             слот: L3-Cache             размер: 3MiB             capacity: 3MiB             возможности: internal unified     *-memory:0 UNCLAIMED          физический ID: 1        *-bank UNCLAIMED             описание: DIMMProject-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>POT-Creation-Date: 2009-10-08 14:02+0200PO-Revision-Date: 2013-01-02 12:27+0000Last-Translator: Aleksey Kabanov <Unknown>Language-Team: Russian <ru@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2013-04-18 12:23+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 16567)X-Poedit-Country: RUSSIAN FEDERATIONX-Poedit-Language: Russian [пусто]             продукт: [Empty]             производитель: [Empty]             физический ID: 0             серийный №: [Empty]             слот: ChannelA-DIMM0     *-memory:1          описание: Системная память          физический ID: 5e          слот: Системная плата или материнская плата        *-bank:0             описание: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0,8 ns)             продукт: 9905403-519.A00LF             производитель: Kingston             физический ID: 0             серийный №: D902E64A             слот: ChannelA-DIMM1             размер: 4GiB             разрядность: 64 bits             частота: 1333MHz (0.8ns)        *-bank:1             описание: DIMMProject-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>POT-Creation-Date: 2009-10-08 14:02+0200PO-Revision-Date: 2013-01-02 12:27+0000Last-Translator: Aleksey Kabanov <Unknown>Language-Team: Russian <ru@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2013-04-18 12:23+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 16567)X-Poedit-Country: RUSSIAN FEDERATIONX-Poedit-Language: Russian [пусто]             продукт: [Empty]             производитель: [Empty]             физический ID: 1             серийный №: [Empty]             слот: ChannelB-DIMM0        *-bank:2             описание: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0,8 ns)             продукт: 9905403-442.A00LF             производитель: Kingston             физический ID: 2             серийный №: 970C0EE7             слот: ChannelB-DIMM1             размер: 4GiB             разрядность: 64 bits             частота: 1333MHz (0.8ns)     *-memory:2 UNCLAIMED          физический ID: 2     *-memory:3 UNCLAIMED          физический ID: 3     *-pci          описание: Host bridge          продукт: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller          производитель: Intel Corporation          физический ID: 100          сведения о шине: pci@0000:00:00.0          версия: 09          разрядность: 32 bits          частота: 33MHz        *-pci:0             описание: PCI bridge             продукт: Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port             производитель: Intel Corporation             физический ID: 1             сведения о шине: pci@0000:00:01.0             версия: 09             разрядность: 32 bits             частота: 33MHz             возможности: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list             кофигурация: driver=pcieport             ресурсы: IRQ:40        *-display             описание: VGA compatible controller             продукт: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller             производитель: Intel Corporation             физический ID: 2             сведения о шине: pci@0000:00:02.0             версия: 09             разрядность: 64 bits             частота: 33MHz             возможности: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom             кофигурация: driver=i915 latency=0             ресурсы: IRQ:45 память:f7800000-f7bfffff память:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(размер=64)        *-usb:0             описание: USB controller             продукт: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller             производитель: Intel Corporation             физический ID: 14             сведения о шине: pci@0000:00:14.0             версия: 04             разрядность: 64 bits             частота: 33MHz             возможности: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list             кофигурация: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0             ресурсы: IRQ:41 память:f7d00000-f7d0ffff        *-communication             описание: Communication controller             продукт: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1             производитель: Intel Corporation             физический ID: 16             сведения о шине: pci@0000:00:16.0             версия: 04             разрядность: 64 bits             частота: 33MHz             возможности: pm msi bus_master cap_list             кофигурация: driver=mei latency=0             ресурсы: IRQ:44 память:f7d1b000-f7d1b00f        *-usb:1             описание: USB controller             продукт: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2             производитель: Intel Corporation             физический ID: 1a             сведения о шине: pci@0000:00:1a.0             версия: 04             разрядность: 32 bits             частота: 33MHz             возможности: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list             кофигурация: driver=ehci-pci latency=0             ресурсы: IRQ:23 память:f7d18000-f7d183ff        *-multimedia             описание: Audio device             продукт: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller             производитель: Intel Corporation             физический ID: 1b             сведения о шине: pci@0000:00:1b.0             версия: 04             разрядность: 64 bits             частота: 33MHz             возможности: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list             кофигурация: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0             ресурсы: IRQ:46 память:f7d10000-f7d13fff        *-pci:1             описание: PCI bridge             продукт: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1             производитель: Intel Corporation             физический ID: 1c             сведения о шине: pci@0000:00:1c.0             версия: c4             разрядность: 32 bits             частота: 33MHz             возможности: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list             кофигурация: driver=pcieport             ресурсы: IRQ:16        *-pci:2             описание: PCI bridge             продукт: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5             производитель: Intel Corporation             физический ID: 1c.4             сведения о шине: pci@0000:00:1c.4             версия: c4             разрядность: 32 bits             частота: 33MHz             возможности: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list             кофигурация: driver=pcieport             ресурсы: IRQ:16 ioport:e000(размер=4096) ioport:f0000000(размер=1048576)           *-network                описание: Ethernet interface                продукт: RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller                производитель: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.                физический ID: 0                сведения о шине: pci@0000:03:00.0                логическое имя: eth0                версия: 06                серийный №: 10:bf:48:e2:ac:4b                размер: 100Mbit/s                capacity: 1Gbit/s                разрядность: 64 bits                частота: 33MHz                возможности: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation                кофигурация: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 ip=192.168.1.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s                ресурсы: IRQ:43 ioport:e000(размер=256) память:f0004000-f0004fff память:f0000000-f0003fff        *-usb:2             описание: USB controller             продукт: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1             производитель: Intel Corporation             физический ID: 1d             сведения о шине: pci@0000:00:1d.0             версия: 04             разрядность: 32 bits             частота: 33MHz             возможности: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list             кофигурация: driver=ehci-pci latency=0             ресурсы: IRQ:23 память:f7d17000-f7d173ff        *-pci:3             описание: PCI bridge             продукт: 82801 PCI Bridge             производитель: Intel Corporation             физический ID: 1e             сведения о шине: pci@0000:00:1e.0             версия: a4             разрядность: 32 bits             частота: 33MHz             возможности: pci subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list             ресурсы: память:f7c00000-f7cfffff           *-network                описание: Беспроводной интерфейс                продукт: AR5212/AR5213 Wireless Network Adapter                производитель: Atheros Communications Inc.                физический ID: 1                сведения о шине: pci@0000:04:01.0                логическое имя: wlan0                версия: 01                серийный №: 00:26:5a:00:44:cf                разрядность: 32 bits                частота: 33MHz                возможности: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless                кофигурация: broadcast=yes driver=ath5k driverversion=3.8.0-27-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.3 latency=168 link=yes maxlatency=28 mingnt=10 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg                ресурсы: IRQ:17 память:f7c00000-f7c0ffff        *-isa             описание: ISA bridge             продукт: B75 Express Chipset LPC Controller             производитель: Intel Corporation             физический ID: 1f             сведения о шине: pci@0000:00:1f.0             версия: 04             разрядность: 32 bits             частота: 33MHz             возможности: isa bus_master cap_list             кофигурация: driver=lpc_ich latency=0             ресурсы: IRQ:0        *-storage             описание: SATA controller             продукт: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode]             производитель: Intel Corporation             физический ID: 1f.2             сведения о шине: pci@0000:00:1f.2             версия: 04             разрядность: 32 bits             частота: 66MHz             возможности: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list             кофигурация: driver=ahci latency=0             ресурсы: IRQ:42 ioport:f0b0(размер=8) ioport:f0a0(размер=4) ioport:f090(размер=8) ioport:f080(размер=4) ioport:f060(размер=32) память:f7d16000-f7d167ff        *-serial UNCLAIMED             описание: SMBus             продукт: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller             производитель: Intel Corporation             физический ID: 1f.3             сведения о шине: pci@0000:00:1f.3             версия: 04             разрядность: 64 bits             частота: 33MHz             кофигурация: latency=0             ресурсы: память:f7d15000-f7d150ff ioport:f040(размер=32)     *-scsi:0          физический ID: 5          логическое имя: scsi0          возможности: emulated        *-disk             описание: ATA Disk             продукт: WDC WD10EZEX-00R             производитель: Western Digital             физический ID: 0.0.0             сведения о шине: scsi@0:0.0.0             логическое имя: /dev/sda             версия: 80.0             серийный №: WD-WCC1S4712514             размер: 931GiB (1TB)             возможности: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt             кофигурация: ansiversion=5 guid=1355bc3b-ae5f-4ef5-ae83-1d670f166649 sectorsize=4096           *-volume                описание: Том EXT4                производитель: Linux                физический ID: 1                сведения о шине: scsi@0:0.0.0,1                логическое имя: /dev/sda1                версия: 1.0                серийный №: 86686fd5-3f53-41bf-932f-883e726f0cf0                размер: 169GiB                возможности: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized                кофигурация: created=2013-08-11 09:58:20 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/media/binliz/86686fd5-3f53-41bf-932f-883e726f0cf0 modified=2013-08-11 09:58:27 mounted=2013-08-11 09:58:27 state=clean     *-scsi:1          физический ID: 6          логическое имя: scsi1          возможности: emulated        *-disk             описание: ATA Disk             продукт: Hitachi HTS54161             производитель: Hitachi             физический ID: 0.0.0             сведения о шине: scsi@1:0.0.0             логическое имя: /dev/sdb             версия: SB4O             серийный №: SB2441GJG8XGBE             размер: 149GiB (160GB)             возможности: partitioned partitioned:dos             кофигурация: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=512 signature=000e19be           *-volume:0                описание: Windows FAT volume                производитель: MSWIN4.1                физический ID: 1                сведения о шине: scsi@1:0.0.0,1                логическое имя: /dev/sdb1                логическое имя: /boot/efi                версия: FAT32                серийный №: 6598-9b1b                размер: 92MiB                capacity: 94MiB                возможности: primary bootable fat initialized                кофигурация: FATs=2 filesystem=fat mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro state=mounted           *-volume:1                описание: Extended partition                физический ID: 2                сведения о шине: scsi@1:0.0.0,2                логическое имя: /dev/sdb2                размер: 148GiB                capacity: 148GiB                возможности: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended              *-logicalvolume:0                   описание: Linux swap / Solaris partition                   физический ID: 5                   логическое имя: /dev/sdb5                   capacity: 7868MiB                   возможности: nofs              *-logicalvolume:1                   описание: Linux filesystem partition                   физический ID: 6                   логическое имя: /dev/sdb6                   логическое имя: /                   capacity: 141GiB                   кофигурация: mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered state=mounted     *-scsi:2          физический ID: 7          сведения о шине: usb@1:1.5          логическое имя: scsi6          возможности: emulated scsi-host          кофигурация: driver=usb-storage        *-disk             описание: SCSI Disk             физический ID: 0.0.0             сведения о шине: scsi@6:0.0.0             логическое имя: /dev/sdc             кофигурация: sectorsize=512  *-power UNCLAIMED       описание: To Be Filled By O.E.M.       продукт: To Be Filled By O.E.M.       производитель: To Be Filled By O.E.M.       физический ID: 1       версия: To Be Filled By O.E.M.       серийный №: To Be Filled By O.E.M.       capacity: 32768mWh uname -aLinux binliz 3.8.0-27-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 9 00:17:05 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Загрузитесь с liveCD и попробуйте по [этой](http://knoppix.ru/adv170604.shtml) схеме, не забудьте в случае необходимости подправьте загрузчик

Comment: Дело в том, что я как бы готов такое осуществить но вот сам вопрос скорее не расскрыл, тот первый раздел это UEFI загрузчик. Может есть люди которые знают как этот самый загрузчик перенести?

Answer (score 0):

Я всегда пользовался gparted'ом, в случаях если это перенос не с HDD на SSD. В последнем случае - не получается. HDD to HDD замечательно копирует. Если надо увеличить разделы - с этим надо будет повозиться. Но тоже возможно.

Answer (score 0):

а если загрузится с livecd и тупо через dd скопировать старый диск на новый? файловые системы можно потом расширить при необходимости.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй сдампить таблицу разделов с помощью

```
sfdisk /dev/sda -d | sfdisk /dev/sdb
```

Ну а потом dd`ой перенеси данные

Comment: Уже не актуально, просто установил туда Ubuntu настроил все под себя и перенес папку home

Comment: Но за ответ спасибо.